# rails rspec stubbing instance variables and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**ProjectsController#show**

```
if !@project.user_allowed_to_view_gallery?(current_user)
  render :action => :hidden_gallery
elsif @project.project_type.gallery_template == :written
  render :action => :written_gallery
end
```

I want to test this action and this is my test file.

```
sign_in @creative
get :show, :id => @project.to_param
controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@creative)
@project.stub!(:user_allowed_to_view_gallery?).with(@creative).and_return(false)
response.should render_template("hidden_gallery")
```

And it doesn't work.I think the problem is stubbing instance @project variable and current_user.Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error, is the output not what you're expecting, what line is it failing on if it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You should expect the response to render a template. Not your project instance.

```
response.should render_template 'hidden_gallery'
```

Comment: I did typo error when I write here.Normally, I use response.should render_template 'hidden_gallery'.So problem is not solved yet.

Comment: I see, ok. You should also setup your stubs on controller and @project before calling 'get :show'. It's probably calling these methods before you even get a chance to stub them.